# Ubuntu server 20.04 SSH login from other Linux box works, using Putty results in connection refused

Tags: server, ssh

I have a fresh install from Ubuntu server 20.04 with OpenSSH. Firewall is disabled.
From a Linux computer I can login to SSH port 22 without problems, from a Windows PC using Putty (same network/IP range) the connection is refused. Ping works in both directions.
Any suggestions ?

Most options in etc ssh_config are still commented out (default,except port 22 which I enabled)

Comment: Try making available screenshots of your putty session configuration screens.
Please also post verbatim whatever messages you get.

Comment: FYI commented values in the (original) ssh_config file indicate defaults anyhow - there should be no need to uncomment the port 22 assignment for example

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the log? Should be in `/var/log/auth.log` I believe